# Which hardware specifications for thin clients connecting to a workstation server?

Tags: linux, thin-client

I want to setup a Linux workstation and Linux thin clients using xrdp and moonlight/sunshine. My use case are mainly software develepment,CAD, photo edition, web browsing, office, supertuxcart.

So I need two video outputs high resolution, sound/microphone forwarding. I want reasonable latency to be able to play real time games sometimes.

What are the minimal and recommanded specifications to reach this goal please, in terms of CPU (cores, thread, hyperthreading, caches), GPU, HW codecs, RAM, etc, possibly recommand some hardware?